# What's the feeling where you feel weird in places where people in movies get stabbed etc

Tags: cognitive-psychology

For example in the matrix, when the little bug crawls through his belly button my belly button feels weird.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing seems to be a form of [mirror touch synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror-touch_synesthesia)

> Mirror-touch synesthesia is a condition which causes individuals to experience the same sensation (such as touch) that another person feels. For example, if someone with this condition were to observe someone touching their cheek, they would feel the same sensation on their own cheek. Synesthesia, in general, is described as a condition in which a stimulus causes an individual to experience an additional sensation. Synesthesia is usually a developmental condition, however recent research has shown that mirror touch synesthesia can be acquired after sensory loss following amputation.

Comment: Or simply, empathy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathy

Comment: This may have to with mirror neurons right? When you are in a conversation with people you also tend to mimic each other's movements as a way of connecting.